# How to get the last record of one column in an already complicated query

Tags: mysql

I have a query that gets me almost everything I need. I've built it with help from other questions on this forum but the last part has me stumped.

```
SELECT barcode, employee
  ,SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, dateandtime, (SELECT IFNULL(MIN(dateandtime),NOW())
                                                  FROM wwtlog b
                                                 WHERE b.barcode = a.barcode
                                                   AND b.dateandtime  > a.dateandtime
                                                   AND b.inorout = 'IN'
                                                )))) timeused
FROM wwtlog a


WHERE inorout = 'OUT' and barcode IN (SELECT t1.barcode FROM wwtlog t1
                                JOIN (SELECT barcode, MAX(dateandtime) dateandtime FROM wwtlog GROUP BY barcode) t2
                                ON t1.barcode = t2.barcode AND t1.dateandtime = t2.dateandtime WHERE inorout = 'IN')


GROUP BY barcode;
```

This gives me unique barcode's, with the employee and the amount of time, but it gives me the first employee record for that each barcode, I need the last employee. I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: is there a way to join this in? it gives me unique barcode's and last employee `code` SELECT t1.barcode, t1.employee FROM wwtlog t1
  JOIN (SELECT barcode, MAX(id) id FROM wwtlog GROUP BY barcode) t2
    ON t1.id = t2.id AND t1.barcode = t2.barcode;

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query